# Adding brackets to template content in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

In MediaWiki 1.33.0 in Hebrew I have the following template by which I show superior content (<sup>1</sup>) as references for data.
I want this data to be wrapped in single brackets so if there are several references they would be separated like <sup>[1][2]</sup> instead <sup>12</sup>.

The basic template I use is this:

```
<span class="footnote"><sup>{{{1}}}</sup></span><noinclude>
[[קטגוריה:תבניות עריכה]]
</noinclude>
```

To achieve the desired result, I have tried the following variations that didn't produce it:

```
<span><sup>[{{{1}}}]</sup></span>
```

and

```
<span><sup><nowiki>[</nowiki>{{{1}}}<nowiki>]</nowiki></sup></span>
```

If at all, how could I achieve the desired result in the current release of MediaWiki?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to produce the desired result using this code:

Markup (HTML-Wiki):

```
<span class="footnote"><sup class="footnote_inner">{{{1}}}</sup></span><noinclude>
```

Style (CSS):

```
.footnote_inner:before {
    content: "["
}

.footnote_inner:after {
    content: "]"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<sup>[{{{1}}}]</sup>` works as long as the parameter is not an URL. `<sup><nowiki>[</nowiki>{{{1}}}<nowiki>]</nowiki></sup>` always works - I suspect you are making some unrelated mistake. (`<sup>&#x5B;{{{1}}}&#x5D;</sup>` would be another way to escape.)

Comment: Hello, if you haven't already - please take a look at the updated question and on my answer. Thanks.